# Logging incoming request HTTP headers in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, log, http-headers, http-post

I have a *GeoServer 2.0.2* and I send *POST* requests using mobile devices. I would like to see how the incoming *POST* request *HTTP headers* are formatted, especially what kind of character encoding and response type are provided by the client.

**How can I setup *GeoServer* and/or *Jetty* to provide me with these informations?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can capture the entire tcp stream using e.g.

```
tcpdump -i interface_name port 8080 -w /tmp/capture
```

after the capture is complete you copy the file from the server to some station and use *wireshark* to decode the capture.

Answer (score 4):

You can install and configure the logback tee filter as documented here:

http://logback.qos.ch/access.html#teeFilter

The Tee filter seems to dump both request and response headers.

**another solution builtin in geoserver, does not meet user requirements**

Edit the web.xml file in

*webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml*

then scroll down until you reach the filter called 'Request Logging Filter' and enable it.
Restart geoserver to apply the new cfg.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't include the HTTP headers.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to either use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or tcpdump the traffic as suggested in another solution.